# If the sentence is unnatural, does that mean it is grammatically incorrect?

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence-meaning, grammaticality

I am not a native English speaker, does native English people **just** say “I look”? **If it is unnatural, does that mean it is grammatically incorrect?**

It is confusing to me because it is Subject+Verb construction but I dont see others just use “I look”.

Thanks.

Comment: We need some context. What do you want it to mean? Can you give us an example of a conversation where you would use this phrase?

Comment: Why would you say just "I look". Someone would have to say something to cause this... that's what I'm trying to understand. Why would you just say "I look"?

Comment: I don't understand your question either.  I can find many examples of "I look" as part of a larger sentence, but are you asking if people say it as a complete sentence?  Where is it that you think people might say it, but you don't see them saying it?

Comment: @stangdon Yes, I am asking if people say it as a complete sentence, if people don't, does that mean the sentence is grammatically incorrect?

Comment: @Catija I know "I look" sound unnatural even I am not a native english speaker, but does that mean "I look" is grammatically incorrect on it's own?

Comment: @towry, most people not only want to say things that are grammatically correct, they also want to say things that make sense. While "I look" is a grammatically complete sentence it's something that would be said very rarely. We want to know if you really mean to say "I see" or "I watch" or something else that would be more common, so we can give you better advice and improve your English.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Yeah it's grammatically correct, but it's a subordinate clause which means, it doesn't make sense on its own.

e.g. 
"**I look** at people differently with a rose-tinted perception"

edit:

**in terms of clauses, it is grammatically correct as a dependent clause**:

'*I look*' is a dependent (subordinate) clause (w a subject + verb construction but not complete thought)

'*I look in the distance*' is an independent (main) clause (w a subject + verb construction **with** complete thought)

**But in terms of full sentences no**:

The most basic of sentences, which is simple sentences; has to have 1 independent clause. Hence, why it's also a minor sentence as it does not have an independent clause that a simple sentence has; it's 'acting' like a sentence.

Hope that clarifies it. :)

Source: https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/sentences.htm

For those, who want to educate themselves on Minor sentences: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Major-and-Minor-Sentences-Regular-and-Irregular-Sentences.htm

Definition of minor sentence: "a word, phrase, or clause functioning as a sentence and having in speech an intonation characteristic of a sentence but ***lacking*** the grammatical completeness and independence of a full sentence"

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't make sense on its own?  I can certainly see it being used like "He asks me to look at his car.  I look." even if that's unusual.

Comment: Because it's also a minor sentence e.g. "yes, indeed" etc. These phrases wouldn't make sense without contextualisation. You contextualised yours. Definition of minor sentence: "a word, phrase, or clause functioning as a sentence [...] but lacking the grammatical completeness and independence of a full sentence."

Comment: @aesking So it must have a context to say it is grammatically correct?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand how it's a "minor sentence".  It has a subject, *I*, and a verb, *look*.  It might require context to give it *semantic* sense, but not grammatical sense.

Comment: "I look" is a complete sentence, not a "minor sentence" as my brief research has described the word. It has a subject and a predicate.  Nothing else is needed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the remainder of this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67009/discussion-on-answer-by-aesking-is-i-look-grammatically-correct), where it is welcome to resume.

Answer (score 7):

The circumstances in which "**I look**"" makes sense on its own as a complete sentence are fairly limited.

Stangdon pointed out that it could be used when recounting a narrative in the present tense (the historic present):

> He asks me to look at his car. **I look**.

Another place it could be used is, for example, in response to this question:

> Q: Why does no one ever look at the weekly newsletter?
>
> A: **I look**.

Still, most speakers would be more likely to say either **I do** or **I look at it**.

There are, however, many occasions where a foreign learner of English might be tempted to say **I look** where it would be incorrect to do so.  For example:

> Can you look at this, please?
>
> OK, <s>I look now</s>. I'll look now *or* I'm looking now.
>
> Look over there!
>
> <s>I look</s>! I'm looking!

Answer (score -2):

I think the reportor use his own language habit to say "I look".
But in English habit, they normal don't express like this. You can say "let me take a look", "Let me see", or other sentences to replace.
Since in English habit, they don't say that, we discuss it make no sense.